# pam_sss(sudo:auth): unknown option: minimum_uid:6000

Tags: rhel, pam, sssd

I've recently tried to convert my Rhel7 configuration to my Rhel9 setup.
I'm running into some issues when it comes to `authselect` and `system-auth` configuration file.

**For Rhel7 I used following:**
`auth sufficient 'pam_ldap.so' minimum_uid=6000 use_first_pass`

**For Rhel9 I've tried:**
`auth sufficient 'pam_sss.so' minimum_uid=6000 use_first_pass`

However for Rhel9 I get the following error in my `/var/log/secure`
`pam_sss(sudo:auth): unknown option: minimum_uid:6000`

Reading the [Krb5 migration](https://docs.pagure.org/sssd.sssd/users/pam_krb5_migration.html) it says `minimum_uid` is called `min_uid`,
does this mean I have to add the following to my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
...
[pam]
min_uid=6000
...
```

I find the whole thing with `authselect` and `system-auth` confusing. Please help.

Comment: its `min_id` not `min_uid`...and yes.

Comment: @symcbean, should this be added to `[pam]` or `[ldap]` ?

Comment: Don't know - try each.